# Is LLMNR used when a local hostname is not found via DNS?

Tags: networking

When a Windows 10 computer searches for a network resource on a local network on which a DNS server exists, if the DNS server says "can't find it" (for example due to a typo), does the computer automatically fall back to LLMNR (assuming that no GPO disabled LLMNR usage) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any official Microsoft documentation, but my testing shows that a Windows 10 client uses these name resolution methods, for a single label name, in this order, for your scenario:

1. DNS
2. NetBIOS
3. LLMNR

For a fully qualified host name, only DNS is queried.

[image]